# The factors of $5^n-3^n-2^n$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility

I have been assigned the following question.

> Let $f(n):= 5^n-3^n-2^n$. Prove that
>
> (a) $p$ divides $f(p)$ for each prime $p$;
>
> (b) $p^{k+1}$ divides $f(n)$ for $n=p^k$, with $p=2,3,5$ and $k\geq 0$;
>
> (c) $p^{k+2}$ divides $f(n)$ for $n=p^k$, with $p=19$ and $k\geq 0$.

#### Progress

I have been able to derive (a) from the [Fermat's little theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_little_theorem). I suspect that (b) and (c) can be reduce to (a), but I have been
unable to do it.

Comment: Hint that should work for each part of (b): $5^{3^k}-3^{3^k}-2^{3^k} \equiv (2+3)^{3^k}-2^{3^k} = 2^{3^k} + \binom{3^k}12^{3^k-1}3 + \cdots + \binom{3^k}{3^k-1}2\cdot 3^{3^k-1} + 3^{3^k} - 2^{3^k} \equiv 0 \pmod{3^{k+1}}$. Something similar might work for (c), I'm not sure.

Comment: Thank you very much. For $p=2$ the same approach but I have trouble for $p=5$.

Comment: $p=5$ is a little trickier, but try $5^n-3^n-2^n = 5^n - (5-2)^n - 2^n$.

Comment: Sorry. You are right. It is ok with $(5-2)^n$ or $(5-3)^n$.

Answer (score 0):

The cases $k=0$ are trivial as $f(p^k)=f(1)=0$.

**Lemma.** $p^{q^k}\equiv p\mod q$.

By simple induction on $k$, as for $k=0$ is trivially true, suppose $p^{q^k}\equiv p \mod q$. We have
$$
p^{q^{k+1}}=p^{q·q^k}=(p^{q^k})^q
$$
and, by induction, we can complete as
$$
p^{q^{k+1}}=p^{q·q^k}=(p^{q^k})^q \equiv p^q \equiv p
$$
(the latter equivalence is because of Fermat's Small Theorem.) $\qed$

---

To prove (b) in general, we will use a simple factorization of the generic binomial $x^p\pm y^p$ as $(x\pm y)(\text{another polynomial})$.

The three cases $p=2,3,5$ are similar but slightly different. First, you can remove the term with base $p$, as $p^{k+1}$ divides $p^{p^k}$ because $k+1≤p^k$.

As induction base we state that $5=5^1$ divides $3+2=3^{5^0}+2^{5^0}$ and similarly for the other combinations. Suppose now that $p^{k+1}$ divides $q^{p^k}\pm r^{p^k}$ (bases and signs are not arbitrary, either $p=5$ and sign is $+$, or $q=5$ and sign is $-$).

The trivial factorization of $x^5+y^5$ is $(x+y)(x^4-x^3y+x^2y^2-xy^3+y^4)$, the factorization of $x^3-y^3$ is $(x-y)(x^2+xy+x^2)$ and the factorization of $x^2-y^2$ is $(x-y)(x+y)$. If we set $x=q^{p^k}$ and $y=r^{p^k}$, we have that
$$
q^{p^{k+1}}\pm r^{p^{k+1}} = (q^{p^k})^p\pm(r^{p^k})^p
$$
and, applying the above factorization, we can writ this as a product
$$
(q^{p^k}\pm r^{p^k})(\dots)
$$
By induction hypothesis, the first term is divisible by $p^{k+1}$. The second term is a sum of products of the $x$ and $y$ as defined above, but now you can use again Fermat to show that the whole term is divisible by $p$. First of all, $x\equiv q$ and $y\equiv r$. Now we can calculate each case separately.

- $p=5$:

$$
x^4-x^3y+x^2y^2-xy^3+y^4 \equiv 3^4-3^3·2+3^2·2^2-3·2^3+2^4 = 55 \equiv 0 \mod 5
$$

- $p=3$:

$$
x^2+xy+x^2 \equiv 5^2+5·2+2^2 = 39 \equiv 0 \mod 3
$$

- $p=2$:

$$
x+y \equiv 5+3=8 \equiv 0 \mod 2
$$

So in each case the right term of the multiplication is divisible by $p$.

---

Solution for (c) follows later.

Comment: I have a question. Are you sure that $p^{q^k}\ equiv p\ mod q^{k+1}$? I cannot understand this point. For me, the problem using induction is that for $n=k+1$ changes the mod to $q^{k+2}.

Comment: I will clarify the generic step in the answer.